# How can I scrape the text from this PDF in an automated way into a csv using Python?

Tags: python, csv, pdf, converters, scrape

I am trying to scrape data from the following PDF.

http://www.maine.gov/ifw/hunting_trapping/pdfs/deerharvest_2015.pdf

I am trying to generate a CSV with each town name and the number from the map.

So far I am thinking it would be easiest to convert it into a JPEG and geocode it into a map and write a python scrip which displays the image from one town at a time and accepts input from the user as to what the number is. Not exactly an automated solution but may work. I would like to scrape these for the past 5 years so an automated solution would be ideal.

Any thoughts??

PS.... I have tried several of the PDF to Text converters available online and unfortunately, due to the unstructured nature of the map, they aren't really able to produce any sort of helpful results

Comment: You can try using `scraperwiki` which will parse the pdf into an xml structure and then use `BeautifulSoup` to parse that and put into a .csv. Bit convoluted but should work.

Comment: i tried that one, it is all pretty jumble up bcause it doesnt seem tofollow a real pattern

Comment: That's the problem with PDF parsing it's a real pain since PDF's are formatted for printing rather than parsing them. That may be the best you can do without some real extensive work.